# cant edit access mdb files, keep getting asp error

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

hallo all. downloaded a forum from a web server 
to my computer so i can work on it.

anyway the mdb files are locked or something like that and i keep getting this error:

Error Type:
Microsoft JET Database Engine (0x80040E09)
Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.
/forum/login_user.asp, line 168

the files are not read-only. i checked that.
what else can it be?...

thanks

Comment: Can you open the mdb with Access? Have you checked that it is not blocked (right-click, properties)? Is the directory read only? Who has permissions on the file?

Comment: yes i can open it with access. when i right click the file it only has general and summary tabs. not permissions tab. its not read only.
the folder is not read only...

Comment: Do any of your files have a security tab?

Comment: lol no actually... didnt see it untill now (its not my main pc)

Comment: Here is one possibility: http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/no-security-tab/160486.html

Comment: When you get it working, check permissions for IUSER

Comment: Ah, yes, @Remou -- the absolutely idiotic SIMPLE FILE SHARING, which is not simpler than the old way at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internet user guest account must have modify rights on the .mdb file.

Go to the place on the server where the .mdb file is stored.

Right click the .mdb file

Click security tab

If the iusr account is there, add the Modify rights (Write will be checked too).

If the iuser account is not there, click 'Add..' , enter 'iUSR' in the object names field and press 'Check names', the full qualified iusr account will be shown, click this underlined name and click 'Ok' , check the Modify, Read & Execute, Read and Write rights and press ok.

You might consider doing this on the folder of where the .mdb file is stored (please store the .mdb files in a seperate folder so that the modify rights only apply to the database files, and no other files on your server).